# Threads and mutex with broadcast signal

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

**In scenario 2 why all threads are not getting triggered?
What is the problem with different mutex variable?**

**Scenario 1 :**

I am creating four threads.Each threads were assigned to different cores all four threads are waiting for signal with same conditional and mutex variable.While passing broadcast signal with same conditional variable all threads were getting triggered.

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<pthread.h>
    #include<sched.h>    
pthread_cond_t condVar=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;        
pthread_mutex_t mutexVar=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;        
void *thread1(void *ptr)        
{        
    int iVar=1;        
    printf("Thread %d\n",iVar);        
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexVar);        
    pthread_cond_wait(&condVar,&mutexVar);        
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexVar);        
    printf("Thread %d is unblocked...\n",iVar);        
}        

void *thread2(void *ptr)        
{        
    int iVar=2;        
    printf("Thread %d\n",iVar);        
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexVar);        
    pthread_cond_wait(&condVar,&mutexVar);        
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexVar);        
    printf("Thread %d is unblocked...\n",iVar);        

}        

void *thread3(void *ptr)        
{        
    int iVar=3;        
    printf("Thread %d\n",iVar);        
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexVar);        
    pthread_cond_wait(&condVar,&mutexVar);        
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexVar);        
    printf("Thread %d is unblocked...\n",iVar);        

}        

void *thread4(void *ptr)        
{        
    int iVar=4;        
    printf("Thread %d\n",iVar);        
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexVar);        
    pthread_cond_wait(&condVar,&mutexVar);        
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexVar);        
    printf("Thread %d is unblocked...\n",iVar);        

}        


int main()        
{        
    int i,j=2;        
    pthread_t t[4];        
    cpu_set_t cpuset;        

    pthread_create(&t[0],0,thread1,0);
    pthread_create(&t[1],0,thread2,0);
    pthread_create(&t[2],0,thread3,0);
    pthread_create(&t[3],0,thread4,0);

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)            //Assign dedicated core for each thread
    {
        CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
        CPU_SET(j,&cpuset);
        if((pthread_setaffinity_np(t[i],sizeof(cpu_set_t),&cpuset))!=0)
            perror("Set_affinity");
        j+=2;
    }
    sleep(5);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condVar);
    while(1);
}
```

**Output:**

Thread 1

Thread 4

Thread 2

Thread 3

Thread 1 is unblocked...

Thread 4 is unblocked...

Thread 2 is unblocked...

Thread 3 is unblocked...

**Scenario 2:**

Instead of same mutex variable I have created different mutex to each thread.While passing broadcast signal among the four,only one thread is getting triggered remaining threads were waiting for signal.

**Output for scenario 2 :**

Thread 1

Thread 2

Thread 4

Thread 3

Thread 1 is unblocked...

Comment: No code for S2?  Also, the code for all four threads is essentially the same, so why do you have four different functions?  That last argument in pthread_create() is useful for something:)

Comment: `pthread_cond_t condVar=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;`
`pthread_mutex_t mutexVar1=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`
`pthread_mutex_t mutexVar2=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`
`pthread_mutex_t mutexVar3=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`
`pthread_mutex_t mutexVar4=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`

   **I have declared cond and mutex as per the code given above. I have assigned four different mutex for four different threads.Remaining codes were same as Scenario 1.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of same mutex variable I have created different mutex to each thread.While passing broadcast signal among the four,only one thread is getting triggered remaining threads were waiting for signal.

That's a misuse of condition variables and undefined behavior. [Per the POSIX `pthread_cond_wait()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html):

> When a thread waits on a condition variable, having specified a particular mutex to either the pthread_cond_timedwait() or the pthread_cond_wait() operation, a dynamic binding is formed between that mutex and condition variable that remains in effect as long as at least one thread is blocked on the condition variable. **During this time, the effect of an attempt by any thread to wait on that condition variable using a different mutex is undefined.**

Comment: You are probably correct here, but it would have been nice to see the code for S2:(

Comment: @MartinJames True, but the description is pretty clearly UB: "Instead of same mutex variable I have created **different mutex** to each thread."